# How can I get information in JSON format from many AWS accounts at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I need to get information such as VPCs, subnets, security groups, etc for many AWS accounts at once. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a for loop with the AWS CLI. Check out the [CLI Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html) for the service that you're wanting to gather information for and find the appropriate commands then use a for loop to loop over the profiles in your `~/.aws/credentials` file.

For example, if you're wanting to get the VPCs, subnets, and security groups, those are all described in the [EC2 CLI docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/index.html).

Here is an example of getting information about those resources and outputting it into the current directory as `.json` (this assumes you didn't change the default output format when using `aws configure`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
region=us-east-1
for profile in `grep [[] ~/.aws/credentials | tr -d '[]'`
do
        echo "getting vpcs, subnets, and security groups for $profile"
        aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region $region --profile $profile > "$profile"_vpcs.json
        aws ec2 describe-subnets --region $region --profile $profile > "$profile"_subnets.json
        aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region $region --profile $profile > "$profile"_security_groups.json
done
```